# PostgreSQL JSON Querying

Tags: json, postgresql

I have a JSON type column called "person" and the data stored in it is in the format

```
{
   "clients":{
      "nbr":"2",
      "info":[
         {
            "nom":"Baptiste",
            "genre":"male",
            "age":"48"
         },
         {
            "nom":"Lisa",
            "genre":"female",
            "age":"29"
         }
      ]
   }
}
```

I want to retrieve the names of clients.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: please show us what you tried for now and what is your current problem. that said, this could help you: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/11/functions-json.html

Answer (score 0):

You may use `json_array_elements`

```
select json_array_elements(person->'clients'->'info')->>'nom'  as name
    from t;
```